# Get the difference in time between multiple rows with the same column name

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I need to get the time difference between two dates on different rows. This part is okay but I can have instances of the same title. A quick example which will explain things some more.

Lets say we have a table with the following records:

```
| ID    | Title   | Date               |
| ----- | ------- |--------------------|
| 1     | Down    |2021-03-07 12:05:00 |
| 2     | Up      |2021-03-07 13:05:00 |
| 3     | Down    |2021-03-07 10:30:00 |
| 4     | Up      |2021-03-07 11:00:00 |
```

I basically need to get the time difference between the first "Down" and "Up". So ID 1 & 2 = 1 hour.

Then ID 3 & 4 = 30 mins, and so on for the amount of "Down" and "Up" rows there are.
(These will always be grouped together one after another)

It doesn't matter if the results are seperate or a SUM of all the differences.

I'm trying to get this done without a temp table.

Thank you.

Comment: Have you tried using `LEAD/LAG`?

Comment: Please show us what you have tried. And explain why you don't want to use a temp table.

Answer (score 1):

This can be done using analytical functions, the availability  of which will be determined based on your sql engine. The idea is to get the next value in the same row as the one you need to calculate the diff/sum

In the case above it would look some thing like below

```
SELECT
    id , 
    title,
        Date as startdate,
    LEAD(Date,1) OVER (
        ORDER BY id 
    ) enddate
FROM
    table;
```

Once you have it on the same row, you can carry out your time difference  operation.